# Set label.backcolor transparency

Tags: vb.net, transparency, backcolor

1) Transparent form (set form.BackColor = TransparencyKey.Color) owned to another external application by the SetParent API. So I can see the external window even if my form is attached over it.

2) On my form there is a 100% opaque label with custom backcolor (under the label I can't see the external window).

3) I try to set the label.BackColor to semi-transparent setting the alfa color value under 255.

4) If I decrease the alfa value... I don't se the below external window... BUT THE OPAQUE COLOR OF MY FORM. Setting alfa to 0 the label.backcolor becomes 100% opaque of my 100% form color.

How to avoid this problem?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please avoid asking multiple questions at once.

Comment: Sorry man, but I have asked A SINGLE question at the point n.4: how to see under my semi- transparent label the owned form instead of the original color of my form (not transparent under the label)

Comment: Is this winforms or wpf?

Comment: WinForms. Both form and label created by IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The .Net native `Label` control doesn't have `Opacity` property, so you need to:

1. Create your own custom `Label` control.
2. Create an Opacity property inside it.
3. Override the `OnPaintBackground` method of this new custom
   Label.

Here is a one I have created:

```
Public Class OpacityLabel
    Inherits Label

    Public Sub New()
        Me.DoubleBuffered = True
    End Sub

    Private _opacity As Integer = 255
    <System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(255)>
    Public Property Opacity As Integer
        Get
            Return _opacity
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _opacity = Math.Max(Math.Min(value, 255), 0)
            Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(e As PaintEventArgs)
        ButtonRenderer.DrawParentBackground(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle, Me)
        Dim tColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(_opacity, Me.BackColor)
        If (tColor.A < 255 AndAlso tColor.A >= 0) Then
            Using solidBrush As Brush = New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(tColor)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(solidBrush, e.ClipRectangle)
            End Using
        Else
            Using solidBrush As Brush = New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Me.BackColor)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(solidBrush, e.ClipRectangle)
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

4. Create it.
5. Build your project.
6. Put it on your form.
7. Change its `BackColor` to whatever you want.
8. Set the `Opacity` property to be a value between 0 and 255.

Comment: Ty for the answer, but the problem is another: I DONT' WANT TO SEE THE FORM UNDER THE CONTROL, BUT UNDER THE FORM... AND UNDER THE CONTROL THE TRANSPARENT FORM IS NOT TRANSPARENT, BUT IT'S OPAQUE AND HAS THE COLOR SET AS TRANSPARENCYKEYS.COLOR. So if I set the control opacity = 0 I simply see the control with the TransparencyKey.Color.